# Extend django-invitations + django-allauth account adapter

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-invitations

I'm using django-allauth and django-invitations. Following django-allauth's docs, I have created a custom adapter so I can override the `get_signup_redirect_url` method

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
class MyAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        # custom redirects here
```

And then in my settings file I have

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'accounts.adapter.MyAccountAdapter'
```

I'm also using django-invitations, whose docs say that for integrating with allauth, I need to set

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'invitations.models.InvitationsAdapter'
```

This obviously causes a problem because then I'm no longer using my custom adapter.

How can I integrate django-allauth and django-invitations while also overriding the adapter `get_login_redirect_url` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is how I solved the problem in django-invitations v1.9. Hopefully it's not relevant in the near future.*

In my project, I have an "accounts" app where I put all my accounts related files. In the `__init__.py` for the app, I put the following delightful monkey patch

```
from invitations import adapters

def new_get_invitations_adapter():
    from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
    return get_adapter()

adapters.get_invitations_adapter = new_get_invitations_adapter
```

It just bypasses the django-invitations logic that works out which adapter to use by always returning the one django-allauth would use. And django-allauth returns the custom one, which I specified in the project `settings.py`.

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'accounts.adapters.MyAccountAdapter'
```